what is wrong with my djikstra algorithm implementation . it is not passing all the test cases?
I'm working on implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Java to find the shortest paths in a graph. While I've written the code below, I'm encountering issues with its functionality. Here's the code:
import java.util.*;
class Graph{
    Map<Integer,List<Edge>>adjacencyList;

    public Graph(){
adjacencyList=new HashMap<>();
    }
    public void addEdge(int source,int destination,int weight){
        adjacencyList.putIfAbsent(source,new ArrayList<>());
        adjacencyList.putIfAbsent(destination,new ArrayList<>());
        adjacencyList.get(source).add(new Edge(destination,weight));
adjacencyList.get(destination).add(new Edge(source,weight));
    }

    public Map<Integer,Integer> dij(int start){

        PriorityQueue<Edge> pq=new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(edge->edge.weight));
        Map<Integer,Integer> distances=new HashMap<>();

        for(Integer node: adjacencyList.keySet()){
distances.put(node,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        distances.put(start,0);
        pq.add(new Edge(start, 0));

while(!pq.isEmpty()){

    Edge curr=pq.poll();
 int curnode=curr.node;
 int currDist=curr.weight;

for( Edge neighbour:adjacencyList.getOrDefault(curnode, new ArrayList<>()) ){

    int newDist=distances.get(curnode)+neighbour.weight;
if (currDist > distances.get(curnode)) {
    continue;
}

    if(newDist<distances.get(neighbour.node)){
 distances.put(neighbour.node, newDist);
 pq.add(new Edge(neighbour.node, newDist));
    }


}




}
return distances; 
    }
}

class Edge{
    int node;
    int weight;

    
        public Edge(int node, int weight) {
            this.node = node;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
}

       
        
    

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int V = s.nextInt();
        int E = s.nextInt();
        Graph graph=new Graph();
        for(int i=0;i<E;i++){
            int ei=s.nextInt();
            int ej=s.nextInt();
            int w=s.nextInt();
 graph.addEdge(ei, ej, w);
        }
int start=0;

Map<Integer,Integer> ans=graph.dij(start);

for(Map.Entry entry:ans.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
}

        }

        
    }

In this implementation, I expect to compute the shortest distances from a specified start node to all other nodes in the graph. However, when I run the code, I'm not getting the expected results
need your help

its failing the hidden test case that i dont have access to.

Just add those that you have access to and a link to the source question?

If you don't have access to the given test cases where it fails, are you able to create some test cases where it fails?  And, as a previous comment said, please add a link to the source question.

What do  you know about failing test cases?  Do you get wrong result? Time limit exceeded? Exception thrown?

Try?

Are you sure the path length won't overflow int and require a long type instead? What are the problem constraints?

The issue lies in the following lines of code inside the dij method.
if (currDist > distances.get(curnode)) {
    continue;
}

If you consider for curNode = start, for each neighbour of start above statement is true so later code never gets executed[Try out this case in paper]. So your final dij code will be:
public Map<Integer, Integer> dij(int start) {
        PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(edge -> edge.weight));
        Map<Integer, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer node : adjacencyList.keySet()) {
            distances.put(node, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        distances.put(start, 0);
        pq.add(new Edge(start, 0));
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            Edge curr = pq.poll();
            int curnode = curr.node;
            for (Edge neighbour : adjacencyList.getOrDefault(curnode, new ArrayList<>())) {
                int newDist = distances.get(curnode) + neighbour.weight;
                if (newDist < distances.get(neighbour.node)) {
                    distances.put(neighbour.node, newDist);
                    pq.add(new Edge(neighbour.node, newDist));
                }
            }
        }
        return distances;
    }

Above is tested with the following test case:
Input:
5 6
0 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 4
2 3 8
2 4 2
3 4 5

Output:
0 0
1 7
2 3
3 9
4 5

